# bash - replace a value in first file looking at other file referring it as line number

Tags: bash, unix

I need to replace the first value in file1.txt with a value from second file file2.txt considering them as line numbers

For ex:

file1.txt

```
3|1|D|A  
3|2|2018-09-11 11:25:13.000000857|2018-09-11 11:26:03.000000459
```

file2.txt

```
12~299673112~S  
12~299673232~S  
13~299673233~W  
13~299673222~W
```

Output

```
13~299673233~W|1|D|A  
13~299673233~W|2|2018-09-11 11:25:13.000000857|2018-09-11 11:26:03.000000459
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: What did you try already?

Answer (score 0):

You may use this `awk`:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="|"} NR==FNR{a[FNR]=$0; next} $1 in a{$1=a[$1]; print}' file2 file1
```

```
13~299673233~W|1|D|A
13~299673233~W|2|2018-09-11 11:25:13.000000857|2018-09-11 11:26:03.000000459
```